# List unicode characters supported by LaTeX

Tags: unicode

I know, that I can define some of unicode characters with something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3B5}{$\epsilon$}`.  However, it appears not necessarily to do that for some characters, which are already supported by the LaTeX engine, e.g. the ones listed in first line of the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
List of some supported unicode characters:
é è ä ¿ … ß œ

List of some non-supported unicode characters%
\footnote{See source, they are not displayed of course!}:
% ε Ω ± −
\end{document}
```

So, is it possible to list all unicode characters supported by the LaTeX engine?

Comment: the list is not fixed. If you load e.g. the fontencoding LGR latex will load the corresponding dfu-file and then ε will be declared. But beside this you can look in T1enc.dfu,  OT1end.dfu and TS1enc.dfu in latex/base. They contain the list of the default setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ulrike commented the list is open and if you use `fontenc` to load a specific font encoding matching Unicode input declarations will be made if there is a matching `.dfu` file.  Also specific packages for CJK scripts or arabic may define large ranges, however by default in the format itself definitions covering the T1 and OT1 and some of OMS encodings are included.

If you look at the for `utf8enc.dfu` file in the base latex directory, which (currently) has the following definitions then tha shows the definitions that are known to the core format but only the subsets t1enc.dfu, ot1enc.dfu and omsenc.dfu are loaded during format creation.

In comments you mention U+00B5 (micro) which is not supported by the default font set (so not supported by the default inputenc mappings) but if you load the TS1 encoding eg via the `textcomp` package, `\textmu` will be defined and `ts1enc.dfu` will be loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

[µ]
\end{document}
```

Note the log of the above file will show

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
```

The files input when making the format are:

`ot1enc.dfu`

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A1}{\textexclamdown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A3}{\textsterling}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AD}{\-}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B8}{\c\ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BF}{\textquestiondown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C5}{\r A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C6}{\AE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D8}{\O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DF}{\ss}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E6}{\ae}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EC}{\@tabacckludge`\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00ED}{\@tabacckludge'\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EE}{\^\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EF}{\"\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F8}{\o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0131}{\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0141}{\L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0142}{\l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0152}{\OE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0153}{\oe}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{\^W}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0175}{\^w}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0176}{\^Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0177}{\^y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0218}{\textcommabelow S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0219}{\textcommabelow s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{021A}{\textcommabelow T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{021B}{\textcommabelow t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0237}{\j}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2013}{\textendash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\textemdash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2018}{\textquoteleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\textquoteright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201C}{\textquotedblleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201D}{\textquotedblright}
```

`t1enc.dfu`

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A1}{\textexclamdown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A3}{\textsterling}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AB}{\guillemotleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AD}{\-}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BB}{\guillemotright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BF}{\textquestiondown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C0}{\@tabacckludge`A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C1}{\@tabacckludge'A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C2}{\^A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C3}{\~A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C4}{\"A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C5}{\r A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C6}{\AE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C7}{\c C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C8}{\@tabacckludge`E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C9}{\@tabacckludge'E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CA}{\^E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CB}{\"E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CC}{\@tabacckludge`I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CD}{\@tabacckludge'I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CE}{\^I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CF}{\"I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D0}{\DH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D1}{\~N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D2}{\@tabacckludge`O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D3}{\@tabacckludge'O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D4}{\^O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D5}{\~O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D6}{\"O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D8}{\O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D9}{\@tabacckludge`U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DA}{\@tabacckludge'U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DB}{\^U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DC}{\"U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DD}{\@tabacckludge'Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DE}{\TH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DF}{\ss}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E0}{\@tabacckludge`a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E1}{\@tabacckludge'a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E2}{\^a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E3}{\~a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\"a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E5}{\r a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E6}{\ae}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E7}{\c c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E8}{\@tabacckludge`e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E9}{\@tabacckludge'e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EA}{\^e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EB}{\"e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EC}{\@tabacckludge`\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00ED}{\@tabacckludge'\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EE}{\^\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EF}{\"\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F0}{\dh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F1}{\~n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F2}{\@tabacckludge`o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F3}{\@tabacckludge'o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F4}{\^o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F5}{\~o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F6}{\"o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F8}{\o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F9}{\@tabacckludge`u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FA}{\@tabacckludge'u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FB}{\^u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FC}{\"u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FD}{\@tabacckludge'y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FE}{\th}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FF}{\"y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0100}{\@tabacckludge=A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0101}{\@tabacckludge=a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0102}{\u A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0103}{\u a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0104}{\k A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0105}{\k a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0106}{\@tabacckludge'C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0107}{\@tabacckludge'c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0108}{\^C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0109}{\^c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010A}{\.C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010B}{\.c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010C}{\v C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010D}{\v c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010E}{\v D}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010F}{\v d}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0110}{\DJ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0111}{\dj}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0112}{\@tabacckludge=E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0113}{\@tabacckludge=e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0114}{\u E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0115}{\u e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0116}{\.E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0117}{\.e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0118}{\k E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0119}{\k e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011A}{\v E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011B}{\v e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011C}{\^G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011D}{\^g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011E}{\u G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011F}{\u g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0120}{\.G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0121}{\.g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0122}{\c G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\c g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0124}{\^H}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0125}{\^h}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0128}{\~I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0129}{\~\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012A}{\@tabacckludge=I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\@tabacckludge=\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012C}{\u I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012D}{\u\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012E}{\k I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012F}{\k\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0130}{\.I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0131}{\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0132}{\IJ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0133}{\ij}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0134}{\^J}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0135}{\^\j}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0136}{\c K}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0137}{\c k}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0139}{\@tabacckludge'L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013A}{\@tabacckludge'l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013B}{\c L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013C}{\c l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013D}{\v L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013E}{\v l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0141}{\L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0142}{\l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0143}{\@tabacckludge'N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0144}{\@tabacckludge'n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0145}{\c N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0147}{\v N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0148}{\v n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014A}{\NG}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014B}{\ng}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014C}{\@tabacckludge=O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014D}{\@tabacckludge=o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014E}{\u O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014F}{\u o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0150}{\H O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0151}{\H o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0152}{\OE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0153}{\oe}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0154}{\@tabacckludge'R}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0155}{\@tabacckludge'r}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0156}{\c R}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0157}{\c r}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0158}{\v R}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0159}{\v r}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015A}{\@tabacckludge'S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015B}{\@tabacckludge's}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015C}{\^S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015D}{\^s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015E}{\c S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015F}{\c s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0160}{\v S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0161}{\v s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0162}{\c T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0163}{\c t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0164}{\v T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0165}{\v t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0168}{\~U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0169}{\~u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016A}{\@tabacckludge=U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016B}{\@tabacckludge=u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016C}{\u U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016D}{\u u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016E}{\r U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016F}{\r u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0170}{\H U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0171}{\H u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0172}{\k U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0173}{\k u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{\^W}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0175}{\^w}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0176}{\^Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0177}{\^y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0178}{\"Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0179}{\@tabacckludge'Z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017A}{\@tabacckludge'z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017B}{\.Z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017C}{\.z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017D}{\v Z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017E}{\v z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01CD}{\v A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01CE}{\v a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01CF}{\v I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01D0}{\v \i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01D1}{\v O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01D2}{\v o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01D3}{\v U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01D4}{\v u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E2}{\@tabacckludge=\AE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E3}{\@tabacckludge=\ae}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E6}{\v G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E7}{\v g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E8}{\v K}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E9}{\v k}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01EA}{\k O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01EB}{\k o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01F0}{\v\j}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01F4}{\@tabacckludge'G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01F5}{\@tabacckludge'g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0218}{\textcommabelow S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0219}{\textcommabelow s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{021A}{\textcommabelow T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{021B}{\textcommabelow t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0232}{\@tabacckludge=Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0233}{\@tabacckludge=y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0237}{\j}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02D9}{\.{}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02DB}{\k{}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E02}{\.B}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E03}{\.b}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E9E}{\SS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200C}{\textcompwordmark}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2011}{\mbox{-}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2012}{\textendash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2013}{\textendash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\textemdash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2015}{\textemdash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2018}{\textquoteleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\textquoteright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201A}{\quotesinglbase}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201C}{\textquotedblleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201D}{\textquotedblright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201E}{\quotedblbase}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2030}{\textperthousand}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2031}{\textpertenthousand}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2039}{\guilsinglleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{203A}{\guilsinglright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2423}{\textvisiblespace}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E20}{\@tabacckludge=G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E21}{\@tabacckludge=g}
```

`omsenc.dfu`

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{\textsection}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B6}{\textparagraph}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\textperiodcentered}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2020}{\textdagger}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2021}{\textdaggerdbl}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2022}{\textbullet}
```

`utf8enc.dfu` includes all the definitions in the base format (but out of space to list here)

Comment: Very well.  However, I still don't have e.g. micro sign, which is defined in the `utf8enc.dfu` file.  I `strace`d the execution of LaTeX to figure out where this file were loaded—but I found nothing.  In particular, the `.dfu` file does not seem to be openned around the loading of `inputenc.sty`.  Is it supposed to be read at all with the code snippet in the question?

Comment: @ryolait hopefully more accurate now